# New vertical tab group is missing from Windows menu in Visual Studio 2013 and later?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tabs

I have just moved to Visual Studio 2013 and I can't find the way to split my code window vertically, so that I have two different files side by side.

In the previous versions I could just create a new window and then move it to the new tab by choosing *Create a new vertical tab group* from Windows menu.

Now I see only *Create a new horizontal tab group* in this menu, there is no more option to create a vertical tab group.

Has this been removed in this version of Visual Studio???

Comment: Be specific, is it truly *missing* from the menu or is it just *disabled*?  Accidents happen, you might just need Tools + Options, Import and Export, Reset.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 supports vertical tab groups. If you see only the "Create a new horizontal tab group" command then you already have two or more horizontal tab groups opened - you can't create simultaneously horizontal and vertical tab groups. Close horizontal tab groups and you will be able to create a vertical tab group.

Comment: same goes to later VS versions, I believe. It is definitely applicable in 2017.

Comment: you can drag out some files and use different grouping for each window -> use windows multitasking to arrange the window's in windows.

Comment: great. I reset window layout and i can find vertical menu