# Is vertical split not available in Visual Studio Community 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

Searched on here and also on MS official doc site, but seems to be no clear answer.

Seen in the screen cap, we can horizontally split the editor, either with 'split' or 'New Horizontal Tab Group'. Is the vertical splitting considered a premium feature, hence not available here?

It's free, so we can't complain much ( It's been a pleasant surprise using it otherwise). But..slightly petty.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849961/new-vertical-tab-group-is-missing-from-windows-menu-in-visual-studio-2013-and-la

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot for the pointer!